# Cleanest way to set styling for formtastic submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, formtastic

I'm using formtastic and Twitter Bootstrap. I would like to automatically set it that all Submit buttons for my formtastic forms will be "btn large primary" and cancel buttons to be "btn large default" without having to copy those stylings manually for formtastic button styling. Mainly if I decide to later change what the "primary" button looks like so I don't have to change it at multiple places.

What is the cleanest way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a variable in the application helper or the helper for that model.

```
@submit_button_css_classes = "btn large primary"
@cancel_button_css_classes = "btn large default"
```

Then in your forms

```
<%= f.action :submit, class: @submit_button_css_classes  %>
<%= f.action :cancel, class:  @cancel_button_css_classes %>
```

Comment: Added some code. Hope this helps. It may not the cleanest up it does make it easy to change.

Comment: shouldn't it be class=>"" ?

Comment: It should be `class`. Thanks for the catch. I will edit my answer.